# volume and volumemount in Prometheus are not applying?Installed Prometheus-operator using helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

Used this values.yaml for Prometheus-operator helm chart

```
prometheus-operator:
  fullnameOverride: prometheus-operator
  prometheusOperator:
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 192Mi
      requests:
        memory: 128Mi
  prometheus:
    prometheusSpec:
      fullnameOverride: prometheus
      routePrefix: /prometheus
      externalUrl: https://prometheus:8443/prometheus/
      retention: 30d
      serviceMonitorSelectorNilUsesHelmValues: false
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 2.0Gi 
        requests:
          memory: 1.7Gi   
      storageSpec:
        volumeClaimTemplate:
          spec:
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                app: my-example-prometheus
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 1Gi

      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: config-vol
      volumeMounts: 
      - mountPath: /etc/prometheus/config_vol
        name: config-vol
```

volume and volumemount in Prometheus are not applying?Installed by providing the dependency in chart.yaml file provided below and by above values.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
- name: prometheus-operator
  version: "8.13.12"
  condition: prometheus-operator.create
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
```

To reproduce this issue install Prometheus-operator with this dependency in chart.yaml and values.yaml and see whether volume and volumeMount provided in values.yaml are applied or not. There is no such error prometheus-operator is in running state but volume and volumeMount are not get applied.

Comment: Hi, can you please check  [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Providing the necessary details, including warnings, errors, and details to reproduce your scenario will not only help you, but enable you to help others with similar issues! That said, can you update your question with some logs and error about the volumes, k8s version and any docs you followed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the volume feature is available since version 8.13.13 of the prometheus operator. Here`s the [commit](https://github.com/helm/charts/commit/ef0d749132ecfa61b2ea47ccacafeaf5cf1d3d77) reference:

```
`prometheus.prometheusSpec.volumes` | Additional Volumes on the output StatefulSet definition. | `[]` |

`prometheus.prometheusSpec.volumeMounts` | Additional VolumeMounts on the output StatefulSet definition. | `[]` |
```

Please update your operator to newer version.